# Erlang Binary Split

Tags: binary, erlang

I need to split a binary like so

```
<<"one|two|three|four|five">>
```

into

```
[<<"one">>,<<"two">>,<<"three">>,<<"four">>,<<"five">>]
```

I'm nearly there

```
binary:split(<<"one|two|three|four|five">>, <<"|">>, []).
```

But I need to make the scope global to split the entire binary and not just the first item. The answer is staring me in the face here http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#split-3 but I'm having trouble working out from the documentation how to specify the scope as global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as usual, blindingly obvious once you have worked it out:

binary:split(<<"one|two|three|four|five">>, <<"|">>, [global]).